# JSON encode not working for MYSQL result Array in PHP 7

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a MYSQL result array which needs to be json decoded.

Below is my code:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $list[] = $row;
}
$response['data']    = $list;
echo json_encode($response);exit;
```

It seems some simple silly thing is missing. The array in the $result is an array from mysql select query.

When i check the output it is showing blank where as i can see the array properly printed out. Do i have to define an array by looping through all values?

Below is my array structure:

```
Array ( [placement_id] => 1130 [name] => Verizon [os_id] => 2494 [profile_id] => 1130 )
```

Solution to my problem:

col1 was having special characters, so removed using below expression inside my foreach loop:

```
$row['col1'] = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]/', '', $row['col1']);
```

Comment: Your question says `json_decode` but your code block has `json_encode`. Also you're setting `$list` and encoding `$response`

Comment: sorry corrected title

Comment: Getting warmer. You set `$response['data']` but that's not in your array dump. I'm pretty sure I know what the problem is but I need to see the full dump to be sure

Comment: there are more fields in response json like status, message etc... that is the reason i am echoing that variable.... not like data is the array and remaining is either integer or string

Comment: Ok... let's try this. After `json_encode` put `echo json_last_error_msg();`

Comment: aaah i got this :: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Comment: Yep, that was it. Check out the duplicate question. You should be able able to debug it now

Comment: @Machavity thanks for support solved the issue, removed non-printable characters from array.